# How to disable the alarm sound in the default Windows 10 timer app

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app

This question is about the [Windows 10 default Alarm & Clock app](http://www.howtogeek.com/225211/how-to-set-timers-alarms-and-stopwatches-in-windows-10/). I'm currently trying to set up a timer so that (for example) after 10 minutes, I get a notification saying something like "time's up".

Unfortunately, while I get a notification, the app accompanies the notification with an **obnoxious beeping alarm sound**. In addition, the volume of the music I am playing through Firefox decreases when this alarm plays, and increases afterwards. I would like to **turn off the sound**. Here's what I've tried:

1. I've tried turning off the sound for that specific app (I'm playing music, so I can't turn the sound off completely), using the app titled "volume mixer". Unfortunately, there is no dedicated volume control for the alarm app. I've tried turning down the "system sounds" volume control, and this has no effect.
2. I've tried changing the settings of the app, but as far as I can tell the app has no settings page, and no way to turn off the volume for the *timer*. (There is a way to turn off the sound for the alarm clock).

If there is no specific "Alarm & Clock" fix, I would be open to using a different app, as long as it wouldn't require me to install something like "Java Run-time Environment", which I don't want to do (security risks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken a look at the "Alarm & Clock" app in Windows 10,
and my opinion of its quality is basically unprintable.

There exist an enormous number of available free alarm applications,
one of whom will surely meet your needs.

See for example these articles for lists of such products and their merits :

[Best Free Timer and Alarm Clock](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-free-timer-alarm-clock.htm)
[Five Best Windows Timer Applications](http://lifehacker.com/5747056/five-best-windows-timer-applications)

Comment: I found this because I'm looking for a way to stop the alarm sound from repeating forever, when I'm not at the PC to turn it off. AFAIK there is no way to stop it, or to select "No sound" for the alarm. How #$%#$ useless! How typically Microsoft! (It could actually be quite usable, if not for this critical limitation. The interface is simple and functional, and all that I need. grrrr..)

Comment: I found "Free Alarm Clock" at the top of your first link, and have installed it. It seems to do the job nicely. In particular, in it's `Options` it has an option for how long to play the sound.

Answer (score 12):

I realize this is an old post, but I was able to mute alarms by going to Windows Settings, then System, then to Notifications & actions. From here, scroll down and click om "Alarms & Clock" - in this box, you can disable alarm sounds

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said we could use software, I made a 3-piece alarm clock. You can download it or copy+paste the code:

## Startup.vbs

this will be the file you place in the startup section of the start menu (All programs panel)

```
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell") 
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd /c $LOCATION$"
oShell.Run strArgs, 0, false
```

Change $LOCATION$ with the location of the third file,

## Popup.vbs

this will be the file with the reminder

```
lol=msgbox("MESSAGE.",0,"REMINDER!")
```

Change MESSAGE. with the body and REMINDER! with the title

## Alarm.bat

this will be the file that checks the date and time and executes Popup.vbs

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
::====SET TABLE====::
SET ACtime=1717
SET ACday=MON 
SET ACmsgloc=C:\Users\Jeremi\Desktop\FaceCensorApp.vbs 
::====SET TABLE====::
title Alarm Clock

goto loop

:k
for %%i in (%ACday%) do (
if "%date:~0,3%"=="%%i" goto loop
)


goto k

====HELP====
HOW TO USE
Set the variables with the set table.

RULES
    1. ACtime is in 24-hr format. Remeber to put just digits no other characters.
    2. ACday is the FIRST 3 letters of the day, no other characters. Monday=MON Tuesday=Tue Wednesday=WED (You get the point?) 
    3. ACmsgloc is the LOCATION of the reminder file. Enter the FULL path (like C:\Users\Joey\Desktop\Popup.vbs
 RULES
 ====EXIT====

:loop
set mytime=%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%

if "%mytime%" EQU "%ACtime%" (
start %ACmsgloc%
exit )  
goto loop
endlocal
```

DOWNLOAD: http://1drv.ms/1M1CnM8

Answer (score 1):

Here is what works for me -- a kludge for sure but does what I need it to do:

First, my requirements were three:

- to play a loud "obnoxious" sound once - so I can hear it through the house - but not repeat in case I am not around
- leave an alert open on the screen so if I did miss the alarm when it sounded I will see it when I get back
- not steal focus when the alarm message pops up

To make this work I installed Free Alarm Clock, then:

- set the same alarms in both Free Alarm Clock and Alarms & Clock
- in Free Alarm Clock I uncheck "Show Message" so it does not steal focus and uncheck "Repeat sound"
- in Settings --> System --> Notifications & actions --> Alarms & Clock: I turn off "Play a sound when a notification arrives"
- in Settings --> System --> Notifications & actions --> Free Alarm Clock: I turn off "Play a sound when a notification arrives" (so it doesn't clobber the sound from Free Alarm Clock)

When an alarm sounds, I get the sound alert from Free Alarm Clock, and two notifications in the Notification Center - the one for Free Alarm Clock goes away but the alert from Alarms & Clock stays.

One thing slightly lacking: an audible snooze because you need to have "Show Message" checked on Free Alarm Clock for snooze - I get the silent snooze message from Alarms & Clock -- this still works for me because if I snooze an alarm I am generally at my computer then and will see the silent snooze message.